# How can I select and copy a chart from a spreadsheet to a doc using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

For example, I have a google spreadsheet which contain a chart, is there any way to copy this chart to a google doc (as an image) using google script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to copy a chart from Google Spreadsheet to a document:

```
function sheetChart()
{
  try
  {
    var sheet = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendImage(myChart());
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}


function myChart()
{
    try
    {
      var data = Charts.newDataTable()
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Month')
      .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'In Store');

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID').getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1,4,2).getValues();

      for(var i =0;i< sheet.length;i++)data.addRow(sheet[i]);
      data.build();

      var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
                  .setDataTable(data)
                  .setStacked()
                  .setRange(0, 40)
                  .setTitle('Sales per Month')
                  .build();
     }catch(err){
            Logger.log(err);
      }
      return chart.getBlob();
}
```

Data added in the sheet is:

```
profitability   sales
11.00   10000
12.00   11000
13.00   12000
14.00   13000
```

Added this code in document script editor and it is copying the chart as image in the doc.

Hope that helps!