# Google-Apps-Script Empty Pictures Copy

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the following script, emedded in a Google-Sheets file, to copy charts as images from a Google-SpreadSheet to a Google-Document. When I open the document there are just emty pictures inside (means you can only see the margin if you click on it).
I know there are similar questions here on stackoverflow but there were no real solutions for that problem. In addition, if I copy the Pictures to Google-Drive they are empty too. Note i don't want to create a new chart per script and copying the data. In my opinion that is a bad solution.

```
 function graphsReport(){

  var doc = DocumentApp.create('Auswertung ' + new Date());

  var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Auswertung').getCharts();
  for(var i = 0;i<charts.length;i++){
      var chart = charts[i];
      var picture = chart.getAs('image/png');
      picture.setName('chart' + i);
      //DriveApp.createFile(picture);
      doc.getBody().appendImage(picture);
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select and copy a chart from a spreadsheet to a doc using Google Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398583/how-can-i-select-and-copy-a-chart-from-a-spreadsheet-to-a-doc-using-google-scrip)

Comment: I agree with you the question is a bit similar. But i want to know what is wrong with my code. I can't imagin that I have to build a new chart in my script and then copying the data source of the existing. I think thats overkill for my purpose. Note, I just want to get an image from the chart to copy it.